# Force a call in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wonder if it was possible to force a call without using the messagebox confirmation (in debug mode for example...)?

I use currently PhoneCallTask ​​to make a call.

(My application should never go on the market place)

Thank you for your answers,

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way to make a call then using `PhoneCallTask()`, even if your app is not going on the marketplace.

Comment: Basic security sand boxing for the phone, even if it is just a local dev app you won't be able to force a call...

Answer (score 1):

The current Windows Phone SDK only provides the `PhoneCallTask` to make calls, and this class shows the confirmation message box, so the answer is no...